# How to capture the value of a variable at a particular value when using seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using a seekbar to set the value of a variable to appear in a custom view.
The value of the variable is calculated in the custom view class. It is called mEquilibriumPrice;
I would like to capture the initial value of that variable but my problem is that whenever I move the seekbar the value of mEquilibriumPrice changes too.
I want to compare the initial and final values of this variable but cannot find a way to capture the initial value.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok .
We have to store the value of the seek bar in two events.

1)MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : this event is triggered when you touch the seekbar. This is the initial value. Save it as `initial_value`

2)MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: This event is triggered when you remove your finger. This is the final value.Save it as `final_value` . then find the difference between `initial_value` and `final_value` in this event.

Comment: unfortunately if I add an ontouch listener to the seekbar then it will not work with an onseekbarchange listener attached.

Comment: Actually, your answer proved to be the correct way to go. Thanks.